# New blueberry plants turning red

Tags: plant-health, blueberries, ph

My new blueberry plants are turning red! These are my second ones after Ii couldn't acidify the soil of the first batch fast enough. Do you think this is pH again? I read it could also be due to cold weather? I'm running out of ideas of what to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftvnt.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the seller, who says it's due to the cold and that they should go green when it warms up.